# How to have text between a top border line in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, cross-platform

How can I do something like this with flutter

Comment: can you share your some  code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a row with expanded and a text between them

```dart
Row(
 children: [
 Expanded(
   child : Container(
     height: 2,
     color: Colors.black
   )
 ),
 Text('some text here'),
 Expanded(
   child : Container(
     height: 2,
     color: Colors.black
   )
 ),
]
)
```